# I keep getting 'invalid character in identifier' when opening a file in python

Tags: python, pickle

So I'm trying to open a file with the following code:

```
open(‘datapickle’, ‘rb’) as f: 
  names, F, approximate = pickle.load(f)
```

However, I constantly get: 
[image]

what can I do to fix this? 
Please help :(

Comment: Those quotes surrounding your strings aren't regular single quotes, so Python doesn't know what to do with them. Make sure you're using an IDE or an editor designed for code, and not a text editor, to write your code.

Comment: The position of the `^` indicates the parser would see this as accessing the attribute `txt’` of an object named `‘datapickle`, except `‘` is invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Those tick characters `‘` are not valid. Use single `'` or double `"` quotes.
2. The correct syntax is `with open(...) as f`. You're missing the `with` statement.

The editor you're using should be highlighting your text in different colors to help you with this. If you don't have an editor that can do this, try downloading [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Atom](https://atom.io/).

Comment: Another `SyntaxError` will show up after this fix. OP is missing the `with` statement

Comment: `‘` & `’` are called [smart quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Quotation_marks_in_English) while `'` & `'` are dumb quotes, at least among programmers.